# Retrieving answered (not empty/null) questions from one_to_one relationship

Tags: django, django-models

I created a website where a User can create a `project`. Once the project is created, the user can answer 10 macroquestions (named: `Firstquestion`, `Secondquestion`...). Each of this macroquestion, contains a sub question (named: `first_one`, `first_two`...).

For example:

- `Project.Firstquestion.first_one` will result in the first answered subquestion for the macroquestion `Firstquestion`
- `Project.Secondquestion.second_one` will result in the first answered subquestion for the macroquestion `Secondquestion`

The user is not obliged to answer any of the subquestion. It can leave them blank.

I want to do some calculation on how many subquestions the user has answered over the total of subquestions.

Therefore, to retrieve if the user answered the questions I tried the following:

```
def project_first_questions(request, project_id):
  answered_first = 0
  not_answered_first =0

  project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)
  projects = Project.objects.all()
  first_one =  project.firstquestion.first_one
  first_two =  project.firstquestion.first_two
  first_three =  project.firstquestion.first_three
  first_four =  project.firstquestion.first_four
  first_five =  project.firstquestion.first_five
  first_six =  project.firstquestion.first_six
  first_seven =  project.firstquestion.first_seven

  first_questions = [first_one, first_two, first_three, first_four, first_five, first_six, first_seven]

  for answer in first_questions:
    if answer:
      answered_first = answered_first + 1
    else:
      not_answered_first = not_answered_first + 1

  percentage_answered_first = round(float(answered_first / len(first_questions)), 2)
  percentage_not_answered_first = round(float(not_answered_first / len(first_questions)),2)
  return percentage_answered_first, percentage_not_answered_first
```

The above **does work**

**HOWEVER**

I think there is an easier way using the queries.

I tried the following:

```
def project_first_questions(request, project_id):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)
   project.firstquestion.objects.exclude(alias__isnull=True).exclude(alias__exact='').count()
```

**BUT** my query does nor work.
I get the error:
`Manager isn't accessible via Firstquestion instances`

My `Projects/models.py`:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    developer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My `Firstquestion/models.py`

```
class Firstquestion(models.Model):
    first_one = models.TextField()
    first_two = models.TextField()
    first_three = models.TextField()
    first_four = models.TextField()
    first_five = models.TextField()
    first_six = models.TextField()
    first_seven = models.TextField()
    developer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.OneToOneField(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Please show your models.

Comment: Edited the question to add my models (the other models, `Secondquestion`, `Thirdquestion`... are similar to the one posted)

Answer (score 1):

#### The error:

The error is full explained on django exception:

> Manager isn't accessible via Firstquestion instances

In plain words, your expression `project.firstquestion.objects` is invalid, because, `project.firstquestion` is an instance of `Firstquestion` class and not the class itself. Then, you can't access the `Firstquestion.objects` manager via `project.firstquestion` instance.

#### About the *"easier way"*:

You are trying to access to model properties as "rows". Also, field `alias` doesn't appear in your models.

#### The real problem:

Your real problem is that you need [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). I suggest to you to move to a squema like this one:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    developer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.OneToOneField(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class MacroQuestion(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    first = models.TextField()
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #set range restriction to number from 1 to 10.

class SubQuestion(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    second = models.TextField()
    macroQuestion = models.ForeignKey(MacroQuestion, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

With normalized squema you can query over `first` and `second` questions freely.